# Logback or Eclipse logger in Eclipse RCP based products

Tags: eclipse, logging, rcp, e4, pde

From Eclipse experts I want to know whether it is good to use log framework `org.eclipse.e4.core.services.log.Logger` provided by Eclipse RCP in RCP based products or shall we use logback in Eclipse RCP? I am using Eclipse E4 for developing. The problem I see with Eclipse logger is it gives warning "Discouraged access: The type 'Logger' is not API". Which one is preferred way of logging in Eclipse RCP development?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Logger` is OK despite the discouraged access warning. There are still a number of e4 APIs which have not been completely finalized and these have this warning.

You may also find `StatusReporter` useful. This can do logging and show error dialogs.

Comment: Thanks for the answer ..will explore `StatusReporter`

Answer (score 1):

As @greg-449's answer says, using the `org.eclipse.e4.core.services.log.Logger` is fine, and the warning can be safely ignored.

For those like me who'd prefer to keep their code free of pesky warnings that shouldn't be warnings, here's how to disable this particular one (same goes for others where you're sure you can safely ignore them).

**1) Configure access rules**

You can get there either directly from the tooltip shown when hovering over the "Discouraged access" warning...

[image: Configure access rules]

... or via your `Project properties` > `Java Build Path` > `Libraries` > `Plug-in Dependencies`

[image: Project properties]

**2) Edit the access rules**

In the list of plug-in dependencies, find the one that you want to override - in this case, it's the `org.eclipse.e4.core.services[version].jar`, expand it, click on its access rules, and then on the "Edit..." button on the right.

[image: Edit access rules]

**3) Add a new rule**

Hit the "Add..." button on the right to open the "Add Access Rule" dialog, and add a rule to make `org/eclipse/e4/core/services/log/Logger` accessible without warnings:

[image: Add access rule]

Hit OK to close the dialog.

**4) Move the new rule up**

The rules are processed top-down until a matching rule is found, so we want the new "Accessible" one to fire before the original "Discouraged" rule. Use the "Up" button to move the new rule, well, up. It should look like this:

[image: New rule added]

Accept all the dialogs, and the warnings should be gone.

Comment: Thanks Amos for the description. Will use your tips.